# 500 Error in Laravel with Ajax post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I've got 6 different routes that can be chosen from an input select. Each selected route then posts to its own database.

The problem is I get a 500 error back for all of them, but on half of them, it actually posts to the database. I've gone through line-by-line, and other than the variable names, the code is identical. Here's an example of one that doesn't work at all.

submit.js

```
  $('#submit-event').on('click', function() {
    event.preventDefault()
    let title = $('#title').val()
    let type = $('#type').val() // for selecting which DB
    let start = $('#start').data('DateTimePicker').date()
    let end = $('#end').data('DateTimePicker').date()

    let data = {
      '_token': token,
      'title': title,
      'start': start,
      'end': end
    }

    console.log(type); // logs the correct POST route

    $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: type,
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    });

  })
```

routes.php

```
Route::post('/createmeeting', [
  'uses' => 'MeetingController@postCreateMeeting',
  'as' => 'createmeeting'
]);
```

MeetingController.php

```
class MeetingController extends Controller
{

    // Get Meeting from DB - works
    public function getMeetings()
    {
      $meetings = Meeting::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
      return $meetings;
    }

    // Add new Meeting to DB - doesn't work (500 error)
    public function postCreateMeeting(Request $request)
    {
      if (!request['_token']) {
        return redirect()->route('calendar')->with(['message' => "You must be logged in"]);
      }
      // Save Meeting
      $meeting = new Meeting();
      $meeting->title = $request['title'];
      $meeting->start = $request['start'];
      $meeting->end = $request['end'];

      if ($request->user()->meetings()->save($meeting)) {
        $message = 'Event successfully added to calendar';
        return redirect()->route('calendar')->with(['message' => $message]);
      }
      return redirect()->route('calendar')->with(['message' => $message]);
    }
}
```

Responses to similar problems suggest a problem with the token, but I test for that here. Any idea where the mistake could be happening?

Comment: `console.log(type); // logs the correct POST route`...can you post that info?

Comment: @Hackerman it logs "createmeeting"

Comment: @u_mulder Do you actually want to help? Obviously I'm still learning, so maybe a little help on reading/finding the error logs? There's nothing in the storage/logs directory. I've added Log::error() and Log::debug() to the controller where I think is appropriate based on the Laravel source docs, but if you think that might help, how to I create and access them?

Comment: @crashspringfield do you know if you have the correct permissions set for your storage/logs directory? Using developer tools in your browser you can also try to view the response returned for the ajax requests giving a 500 error. If you are not in production and have debug set to true it should output the error there

Comment: @MarkusTenghamn Thanks for that tip on being able to see the response in the Devtools. I'm used to Node where I can just throw in a dozen console.logs until I find the issue. I ended up rewriting the controller and model from scratch and it worked so it must have just been a typo I was overlooking.